# session not working on multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am currently having a hard time on upgrading my code by using sessions. the case is about webcart. I am now at the add to cart process. I want to use sessions to retain the chosen item by the user. but it seems that every time i use this sessions, there is no occurence of this action. please help me on this problem. btw, this is the code.

```
<?php session_start();
        $q1=isset($_REQUEST['attack']) ? $_REQUEST['attack'] : 'no_value'; 
        if(is_numeric($q1)){ $q1=number_format($q1,0);}
        $q2=isset($_REQUEST['binge']) ? $_REQUEST['binge'] : 'no_value';
        if(is_numeric($q2)){ $q2=number_format($q2,0);}
        $q3=isset($_REQUEST['con']) ? $_REQUEST['con'] : 'no_value';
        if(is_numeric($q3)){ $q1=number_format($q3,0);}
        $q4=isset($_REQUEST['dan_ph']) ? $_REQUEST['dan_ph'] : 'no_value';
        if(is_numeric($q4)){ $q1=number_format($q4,0);}
        $q5=isset($_REQUEST['childeden']) ? $_REQUEST['childeden'] : 'no_value';
        if(is_numeric($q5)){ $q1=number_format($q5,0);}
        $q6=isset($_REQUEST['userevie']) ? $_REQUEST['userevie'] : 'no_value';
        if(is_numeric($q6)){ $q1=number_format($q6,0);}
        $q7=isset($_REQUEST['maze']) ? $_REQUEST['maze'] : 'no_value';
        if(is_numeric($q7)){ $q1=number_format($q7,0);}
        $q8=isset($_REQUEST['annefrank']) ? $_REQUEST['annefrank'] : 'no_value';
        if(is_numeric($q8)){ $q1=number_format($q8,0);}
        $q9=isset($_REQUEST['pewds']) ? $_REQUEST['pewds'] : 'no_value';
        if(is_numeric($q9)){ $q1=number_format($q9,0);}

        $_SESSION['bookrec']=array(
        'book1'=>array('callno'=>123005,'price'=>1380,'desc'=>'Attack on Titan Anthology','auth'=>'Scott Synder','quant'=>(int)$q1,'total'=>1380*(int)$q1),
        'book2'=>array('callno'=>123006,'price'=>number_format(844,2),'desc'=>'Binge','auth'=>'Tyler Oakley','quant'=>(int)$q2,'total'=>number_format(844,2)*(int)$q2),
        'book3'=>array('callno'=>123004,'price'=>number_format(598,2),'desc'=>'A Work in Progress','auth'=>'Connor Franta','quant'=>(int)$q3,'total'=>number_format(598,2)*(int)$q3),
        'book4'=>array('callno'=>123003,'price'=>number_format(668,2),'desc'=>'The Amazing Book is Not on Fire','auth'=>'Dan Howell, Phil Lester','quant'=>(int)$q4,'total'=>number_format(668,2)*(int)$q4),
        'book5'=>array('callno'=>123002,'price'=>number_format(760,2),'desc'=>'Children of Eden: A Novel','auth'=>'Joey Graceffa','quant'=>(int)$q5,'total'=>number_format(760,2)*(int)$q5),
        'book6'=>array('callno'=>123008,'price'=>number_format(799,2),'desc'=>'Username : Evie','auth'=>'Joe Sugg','quant'=>(int)$q6,'total'=>number_format(799,2)*(int)$q6),
        'book7'=>array('callno'=>123009,'price'=>number_format(440,2),'desc'=>'The Maze Runner','auth'=>'James Dashner','quant'=>(int)$q7,'total'=>number_format(440,2)*(int)$q7),
        'book8'=>array('callno'=>123007,'price'=>number_format(572,2),'desc'=>'Anne Frank: The Biography','auth'=>'Melissa Muller','quant'=>(int)$q8,'total'=>number_format(572,2)*(int)$q8),
        'book9'=>array('callno'=>123001,'price'=>number_format(699,2),'desc'=>'This Book Loves You','auth'=>'Pewdiepie','quant'=>(int)$q9,'total'=>number_format(699,2)*(int)$q9)
        );
        $SESSION['selected']=array();
        $selected=$SESSION['selected'];

        $b1=implode("<td>",(array)$_SESSION['bookrec']['book1']);
        $b2=implode("<td>",(array)$_SESSION['bookrec']['book2']);
        $b3=implode("<td>",(array)$_SESSION['bookrec']['book3']);
        $b4=implode("<td>",(array)$_SESSION['bookrec']['book4']);
        $b5=implode("<td>",(array)$_SESSION['bookrec']['book5']);
        $b6=implode("<td>",(array)$_SESSION['bookrec']['book6']);
        $b7=implode("<td>",(array)$_SESSION['bookrec']['book7']);
        $b8=implode("<td>",(array)$_SESSION['bookrec']['book8']);
        $b9=implode("<td>",(array)$_SESSION['bookrec']['book9']);

        $bo1=$_SESSION['bookrec']['book1']['total'];
        $bo2=$_SESSION['bookrec']['book2']['total'];
        $bo3=$_SESSION['bookrec']['book3']['total'];
        $bo4=$_SESSION['bookrec']['book4']['total'];
        $bo5=$_SESSION['bookrec']['book5']['total'];
        $bo6=$_SESSION['bookrec']['book6']['total'];
        $bo7=$_SESSION['bookrec']['book7']['total'];
        $bo8=$_SESSION['bookrec']['book8']['total'];
        $bo9=$_SESSION['bookrec']['book9']['total'];


                If(isset($_POST['book1'])){
                    foreach($_SESSION['bookrec'] as $data){
                        if($data == $_SESSION['bookrec']['book1']){
                            $selected=$bo1; 
                            $SESSION['selected']=$selected;
                            echo "<table class='w3-table w3-khaki'><tr><td>&nbsp".$b1."</td></tr></table>";
                        }
                    }   
                }
                If(isset($_POST['book2'])){
                    foreach($_SESSION['bookrec'] as $data){
                        if($data == $_SESSION['bookrec']['book2']){
                            $selected[]=$bo2; 
                            echo "<table class='w3-table w3-khaki'><tr><td>&nbsp".$b2."</td></tr></table>";
                        }
                    }   
                }
                If(isset($_POST['book3'])){
                    foreach($_SESSION['bookrec'] as $data){
                        if($data == $_SESSION['bookrec']['book3']){
                            $selected[]=$bo3; 
                            echo "<table class='w3-table w3-khaki'><tr><td>&nbsp".$b3."</td></tr></table>";
                        }
                    }   
                }
                If(isset($_POST['book4'])){
                    foreach($_SESSION['bookrec'] as $data){
                        if($data == $_SESSION['bookrec']['book4']){
                            $selected[]=$bo4; 
                            echo "<table class='w3-table w3-khaki'><tr><td>&nbsp".$b4."</td></tr></table>";
                        }
                    }   
                }
                If(isset($_POST['book5'])){
                    foreach($_SESSION['bookrec'] as $data){
                        if($data == $_SESSION['bookrec']['book5']){
                            $selected[]=$bo5; 
                            echo "<table class='w3-table w3-khaki'><tr><td>&nbsp".$b5."</td></tr></table>";
                        }
                    }
                }
                If(isset($_POST['book6'])){
                    foreach($_SESSION['bookrec'] as $data){
                        if($data == $_SESSION['bookrec']['book6']){
                            $selected[]=$bo6; 
                            echo "<table class='w3-table w3-khaki'><tr><td>&nbsp".$b6."</td></tr></table>";
                        }
                    }
                }
                If(isset($_POST['book7'])){
                    foreach($_SESSION['bookrec'] as $data){
                        if($data == $_SESSION['bookrec']['book7']){
                            $selected[]=$bo7; 
                            echo "<table class='w3-table w3-khaki'><tr><td>&nbsp".$b7."</td></tr></table>";
                        }
                    }
                }
                If(isset($_POST['book8'])){
                    foreach($_SESSION['bookrec'] as $data){
                        if($data == $_SESSION['bookrec']['book8']){
                            $selected[]=$bo8; 
                            echo "<table class='w3-table w3-khaki'><tr><td>&nbsp".$b8."</td></tr></table>";
                        }
                    }
                }
                If(isset($_POST['book9'])){
                    foreach($_SESSION['bookrec'] as $data){
                        if($data == $_SESSION['bookrec']['book9']){
                            $selected[]=$bo9; 
                            echo "<table class='w3-table w3-khaki'><tr><td>&nbsp".$b9."</td></tr></table>";
                        }
                    }
                }
                If(empty(isset($_POST['book1'])) &&  empty(isset($_POST['book2'])) && empty(isset($_POST['book3'])) && empty(isset($_POST['book4'])) && empty(isset($_POST['book5']))  && empty(isset($_POST['book6'])) && empty(isset($_POST['book7'])) && empty(isset($_POST['book8'])) && empty(isset($_POST['book9'])) ){
                    echo "<table class='w3-table w3-khaki'><tr><td>No items yet<td></tr></table>";
                }

                echo "<center><b>TOTAL AMOUNT:</b> Php ".number_format(array_sum((array)$selected),2)."</center>";

                ?>
```

Comment: you should  reduce something irrelevant code.

Comment: Mattia Dinosaur ---- like? ive done research about this but it seems its not working please help me

Comment: there are too much code,you should reduce them .we  do not want to read each line.

Comment: ok ok.. ill reduce this..

Answer (score 0):

There May Be foll0wing resons for that

1) you can not get session value on the same request for the same page

2) if your server is connected to the router then you need to use db based session.